# Show $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot e^{-tx} $ is convergent for fixed $t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that 
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot e^{-tx} \in \mathcal{L}^1$$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$ and a fixed $t$

I have that
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot e^{-tx}\leq \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{tx}}=\frac{1}{x} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{tx} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$

My problem is to prove that the last inequality is actually true and that the function converges

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\sin x| \leq x$ for all $x \geq 0$ and $e^{-tx}$ is integrable if $t >0$. (You have to assume that $t >0$). [ $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx}dx=\frac 1 t$].

Answer (score 2):

As $\vert \sin x \vert \le \vert x \vert$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$, you have

$$\left\vert \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot e^{-tx} \right\vert\le e^{-tx}$$

Hence the convergence of the integral for $t >0$.

Comment: You probably want to take the absolute value on the left-hand side ...

Comment: For sure, you're right!!!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net How do you know that $e^{-tx}$ is convergent?

Comment: The antiderivative of $x \mapsto e^{-tx}$ is $-\frac{1}{t}e^{-tx}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-tx} = 0$ for $t>0$.